Issue with deploying my app via Dockerfile on Github Actions to Azure
I'm running into an issue with my Docker setup while trying to build a Svelte project using Vite. Everything works fine locally, but the build fails in the Docker environment with the following error:
Could someone please help me ?
#8 [ 5/10] RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm install

#8 0.745 npm warn ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

#8 0.746 npm warn While resolving: svelte-hmr@0.16.0

#8 0.746 npm warn Found: svelte@5.15.0

#8 0.746 npm warn node_modules/svelte

#8 0.746 npm warn dev svelte@"^5.0.0" from the root project

#8 0.746 npm warn 11 more (@sveltejs/kit, u/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte, ...)

#8 0.746 npm warn

#8 0.746 npm warn Could not resolve dependency:

#8 0.746 npm warn peer svelte@"^3.19.0 || ^4.0.0" from svelte-hmr@0.16.0

#8 0.746 npm warn node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/node_modules/svelte-hmr

#8 0.746 npm warn svelte-hmr@"^0.16.0" from u/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte@3.1.2

#8 0.746 npm warn node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte

#8 0.746 npm warn

#8 0.746 npm warn Conflicting peer dependency: svelte@4.2.19

#8 0.746 npm warn node_modules/svelte

#8 0.746 npm warn peer svelte@"^3.19.0 || ^4.0.0" from svelte-hmr@0.16.0

#8 0.746 npm warn node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte/node_modules/svelte-hmr

#8 0.746 npm warn svelte-hmr@"^0.16.0" from u/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte@3.1.2

#8 0.746 npm warn node_modules/@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte

#8 0.804 npm warn ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency

#8 0.804 npm warn While resolving: u/melt-ui/svelte@0.76.2

#8 0.804 npm warn Found: svelte@5.15.0

#8 0.804 npm warn node_modules/svelte

#8 0.804 npm warn dev svelte@"^5.0.0" from the root project

#8 0.804 npm warn 11 more (@sveltejs/kit, u/sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte, ...)

#8 0.804 npm warn

#8 0.804 npm warn Could not resolve dependency:

#8 0.804 npm warn peer svelte@">=3 <5" from u/melt-ui/svelte@0.76.2

#8 0.804 npm warn node_modules/bits-ui/node_modules/@melt-ui/svelte

#8 0.804 npm warn u/melt-ui/svelte@"0.76.2" from bits-ui@0.21.16

#8 0.804 npm warn node_modules/bits-ui

#8 0.804 npm warn

#8 0.804 npm warn Conflicting peer dependency: svelte@4.2.19

#8 0.804 npm warn node_modules/svelte

#8 0.804 npm warn peer svelte@">=3 <5" from u/melt-ui/svelte@0.76.2

#8 0.804 npm warn node_modules/bits-ui/node_modules/@melt-ui/svelte

#8 0.804 npm warn u/melt-ui/svelte@"0.76.2" from bits-ui@0.21.16

#8 0.804 npm warn node_modules/bits-ui

#8 5.408

#8 5.408 added 255 packages, changed 1 package, and audited 319 packages in 5s

#8 5.409

#8 5.409 82 packages are looking for funding

#8 5.409 run `npm fund` for details

#8 5.419

#8 5.419 4 low severity vulnerabilities

#8 5.419

#8 5.419 To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:

#8 5.419 npm audit fix --force

#8 5.419

#8 5.419 Run `npm audit` for details.

#8 5.420 npm notice

#8 5.420 npm notice New major version of npm available! 10.8.2 -> 11.0.0

#8 5.420 npm notice Changelog:

#8 5.420 npm notice To update run: npm install -g npm@11.0.0

#8 5.420 npm notice

#8 DONE 5.9s

#9 [ 6/10] RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm run build

#9 0.310

#9 0.310 > frontend@0.0.1 build

#9 0.310 > vite build --emptyOutDir

#9 0.310

#9 0.363 node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265

#9 0.363 throw new ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND(

#9 0.363 ^

#9 0.363

#9 0.363 Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '/usr/src/app/learnify/frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Cyk9bIUq.js' imported from /usr/src/app/learnify/frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/cli.js

#9 0.363 at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:265:11)

#9 0.363 at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:933:10)

#9 0.363 at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1169:11)

#9 0.363 at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:542:12)

#9 0.363 at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:510:25)

#9 0.363 at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:239:38)

#9 0.363 at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:40)

#9 0.363 at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:95:36) {

#9 0.363 code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

#9 0.363 url: 'file:///usr/src/app/learnify/frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Cyk9bIUq.js'

#9 0.363 }

#9 0.363

#9 0.363 Node.js v20.18.1

#9 ERROR: process "/bin/sh -c cd learnify/frontend && npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

------

> [ 6/10] RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm run build:

0.363 at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:542:12)

https://github.com/npm/cli/releases/tag/v11.0.0

0.363 at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:510:25)

0.363 at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:239:38)

0.363 at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:96:40)

0.363 at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:95:36) {

0.363 code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND',

0.363 url: 'file:///usr/src/app/learnify/frontend/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-Cyk9bIUq.js'

0.363 }

0.363

0.363 Node.js v20.18.1

------

./Dockerfile:12

--------------------

10 |

11 | RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm install

12 | >>> RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm run build

13 | RUN rm -r frontend

14 |

--------------------

ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd learnify/frontend && npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

Error: buildx failed with: ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c cd learnify/frontend && npm run build" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1

This is my Dockerfile:
FROM openjdk:21-jdk-slim
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl \
  && curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_20.x | bash - \
  && apt-get install -y nodejs \
  && curl -L https://www.npmjs.com/install.sh | npm_install="10.9.0" | sh

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY . .

RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm install
RUN cd learnify/frontend && npm run build
RUN rm -r frontend

RUN sed -i 's/\r$//' mvnw
RUN chmod +x mvnw
RUN ./mvnw package



EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/usr/src/app/target/learnify-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]

I am trying to build the Project but it doesn't work as it cannot find a node_module but it exists locally. I tried downgrading the version of vite and nodejs but that didn't help either.

It might related to node version either you can run npm install svelte@^4.0.0  or npm install --legacy-peer-deps finally you can check via running this
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json npm cache clean --force npm install
